# Expressions in statements must only be executed for their side effects

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm having a rather unusual problem with this code in unity, I keep getting the error "Expressions in statements must only be executed for their side-effects", I went around the web searching for the problem but all the answers were different, the line that is giving the error is (47,44) which is the `AnimObj.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play` thanks in advance for the help -_-;

```
var CrossObject : GameObject;
var MechanicsObject : GameObject;
var ClipCount : int;
var ReserveCount : int;
var ReloadAvailable : int;
var AnimObj : GameObject;
var ScriptObj : GameObject;


function Update () {
    ClipCount = GlobalAmmo.LoadedAmmo;
    ReserveCount = GlobalAmmo.CurrentAmmo;

    if (ReserveCount == 0) {
        ReloadAvailable = 0;
    } else {
        ReloadAvailable = 10 - ClipCount;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Reload")) {
        if (ReloadAvailable >=1) {
            if (ReserveCount <= ReloadAvailable) {
                GlobalAmmo.LoadedAmmo += ReserveCount;
                GlobalAmmo.CurrentAmmo -= ReserveCount;
                ActionReload();
            } else {
                GlobalAmmo.LoadedAmmo += ReloadAvailable;
                GlobalAmmo.CurrentAmmo -= ReloadAvailable;
                ActionReload();
            }
        }
        EnableScripts();
    }
}

function EnableScripts () {
    yield WaitForSeconds(1);
    ScriptObj.GetComponent("Fire").enabled=true;
    CrossObject.SetActive(true);
    MechanicsObject.SetActive(true);
}

function ActionReload () {
    ScriptObj.GetComponent("Fire").enabled=false;
    CrossObject.SetActive(false);
    MechanicsObject.SetActive(false);
    AnimObj.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, [`Animation.Play()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) is a function not a variable. You are accessing that as a variable by not including `()` at the end of Play.

It should be:

```
AnimObj.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play();
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped